# Replacing SKU with unit price in email confirmation of order?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

G'day,
I've never worked with Magento before, so forgive my bull-in-a-china shop blundering.
I've been asked to replace the SKU with the items unit price in the order confirmation email, and after some googling, have found this howto :

[Add Unit Price To Order Email Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/add-unit-price-to-order-email-template)

Which is pretty close, it leaves the Sku in and adds an extra column, that's just HTML tables and I think I get that.

BUT

Is this the right way to do it?  Reading through other howtos on how to muck about with order PDF's suggests that you should not go editing the base templates and code, but should instead use a local override in the `app/code/local` tree

Is that the case for this modification, is editing these files :

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml
```

The right way?  Or am I creating a maintenance disaster?

Magento 1.9

Comment: Yeah, you're creating a maintenance disaster. You need to add the changes to a local pool module that overrides the core templates

Comment: Understood - so the next question, "how?".  Pointers to the right bit of the doco much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy this files from base template to your template and edit it as you want